# Javascript - how to find the PID where match found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, command-line

I have following string as buffer (they are random rows with random column values).

how can i search for exactly "Warnning" in which ROW available, from that found ROW, how do i filter the PID?

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('TASKLIST /v /FI "IMAGENAME eq python*"', function(a,b,c) {
  console.log(b);
  // Which PID contain the word : "Warnning" ? can you list them chronologically?


});
```

Output:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage Status          User Name                                              CPU Time Window Title
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============ =============== ================================================== ============ =====================================================
python.exe                    9999 RDP-Tcp#10                 1     19?556 K Running         sun\tpt                                                 0:00:15 Warnning of windows
python.exe                    3861 RDP-Tcp#10                 1     19?556 K Running         sun\tpt                                                 0:00:15 Cancle this crap
python.exe                    8080 RDP-Tcp#10                 1     19?556 K Running         sun\tpt                                                 0:00:15 Warnning of windows
```

Comment: You could split the string by line ending using `var lines = b.split('\r\n');` or maybe better to use `var endOfLine = require('os').EOL; var lines = b.split(endOfLine);` then in for loop check if line contains Warning `if(lines[i].indexOf('Warning') > -1) console.log(lines[i]);` Now to get pid you probably need regex but I'm not good at that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the exec filter provide the necessary filter in place of Running.

```
exec('TASKLIST /v /fi "STATUS eq Running" /FI "IMAGENAME eq Shoretel*" /FO csv /NH', 
    function(a,b,c) {

      // function to get the pids
      function getPID(csv){
          var pids = [];
          var lines=csv.split("\n");
          for(var i=0;i<lines.length - 1;i++){
              var headers=lines[i].split('",');
              pids.push(headers[1].split('"')[1]);
          }
          return pids;
      }

      // to get the pids
      getPID(b);
});
```